# How to create stock candle chart with patches in netlogo?

Tags: patch, netlogo, candlestick-chart

I want to draw a candle chart of a stock's historical data using patches, so that this candle chart is like a background where turtles can running on top of it. are patches alone capable of this task or do I have to use turtles instead of patches? I would prefer to use patches.

I am new to netlogo and I didn't find any available model example doing it. So, I wonder anyone can point out the way how I could achieve it.

Thanks a lot

Kenny

Comment: Is the chart going to always be the same size? Patches are squares so it would be relatively easy to create a candle chart with a fixed size by colouring patches (with `set pcolor ...`) but the tricky bit is then working out which patches to apply the graph colour (say green) and which to colour as background (say black).

Comment: Check out the Rugby model (under Sample Models -> Mathematics), it has a plot made out of patches.

Comment: @JenB you are right about finding out which patch to color is tricky, and it may be even trickier to do is how to draw a stick(line) throughout the candle using patches

Comment: @SethTisue, thanks, the model looks promising and I will look into it